Cloudinary Image Optimization HTTP 400
I am trying to use Cloudinary Image Optimization. In most cases it works fine but if there are spaces in the image URL it returns HTTP 400 Bad Request.
Original Image URL:
https://arena.wien/EventDb-Images/GATECREEPER%20euro%20dark%20superstition%20tour%20flyer%20ALL%20DIGITAL.jpg?w=743&q=60
I tried the following Cloudinary URLs:

https://res.cloudinary.com/CLOUDINARY_TENANT/image/fetch/w_200/q_auto:best/f_auto/https%3A%2F%2Farena.wien%2FEventDb-Images%2FGATECREEPER%20euro%20dark%20superstition%20tour%20flyer%20ALL%20DIGITAL.jpg%3Fw%3D743%26q%3D60

https://res.cloudinary.com/CLOUDINARY_TENANT/image/fetch/w_200/q_auto:best/f_auto/https%3A%2F%2Farena.wien%2FEventDb-Images%2FGATECREEPER%2520euro%2520dark%2520superstition%2520tour%2520flyer%2520ALL%2520DIGITAL.jpg%3Fw%3D743%26q%3D60


Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

I don't understand why this question has been closed. Cloudinary Image Optimization is obviously a tool that is mainly used by programmers.

Testing the same link works https://res.cloudinary.com/acjoshi/image/fetch/w_200/q_auto:best/f_auto/https://arena.wien/EventDb-Images/GATECREEPER%20euro%20dark%20superstition%20tour%20flyer%20ALL%20DIGITAL.jpg?w=743&q=60
Note that while some characters have to be escaped for the sake of the browser, [/ and ,] must be double escaped for Cloudinary, as described here:
http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521512-How-to-add-a-slash-character-in-text-overlays-

Thanks. For some reason it does not work with my tenant. I only replaced 'acjoshi'.
